# How select a child with a parameter into React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, foreach

Hey I want to pass a parameter in my function and use it to select a child of my json parse. Is it possible ?

I want to use a function (checkMatch) to check if in my DB I have a username who match with the value input. If it's the case it will return 1 otherwise 0.

But I would do it with password and mail so I need a function where I can just remplace the child of users (example : user.username or user.password or user.mail) and the value of the input.

My json file is really simple :

```js
{
  "users": [
    {
      "mail": "u@u.u",
      "password": 10000,
      "username": "Ugo"
    },
    {
      "mail": "a@a.a",
      "password": 10000,
      "username": "Alice"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my code too :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './SignIn.css';


class SignIn extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        valueUsername: '',
        valuePassword: '',
        users: []
      };

      this.changeUsername = this.changeUsername.bind(this);
      this.changePassword = this.changePassword.bind(this);
      this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
      this.checkMatch = this.checkMatch.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      fetch('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpAwmuxaqa?indent=2')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({users: data.users}));
    }
  
    changeUsername(event) {
      this.setState({valueUsername: event.target.value}); 
      let match = this.checkMatch('username', event.target.value); // I don't know by what remplace 'username'
      console.log(match);
    }

    changePassword(event) {
      this.setState({valuePassword: event.target.value});
      let match = this.checkMatch(this.state.users.password, this.state.valuePassword);
      console.log(match);
    }
  
    submitForm(event) {
      alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.valueUsername);
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    checkMatch(elem, value) {
      let users = this.state.users;
      let valueMatch = 0;

      users.forEach((user) => {
        if (user.elem === value) // I can't concatenate to obtain 'user.username'. So how can I do that ?
          valueMatch = 1;
      });
      return valueMatch;
    }
  
    render() { // the render part isn't important
      return (
        <form id='SignIn_form' onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
            <div id='SignIn_emptyInput'></div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" value={this.state.valueUsername} onChange={this.changeUsername} />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.valuePassword} onChange={this.changePassword} />
            <input id='submit' type="submit" value="SIGN IN" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
  export default SignIn;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Thx for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider following code snippet for the same:

```
users.forEach((user) => {

        if (user[elem] === value) {
           valueMatch = 1;
        }
});
```

*user.elem*  looks for the `elem` key in user object while `elem` is your variable. So you should write  *user[elem]*.

Comment: Thx mate ! That works. I found an other solution too :

users.forEach((user) => {
        if (user[elem] === value)
          valueMatch = 1;
      });
      return valueMatch;

Comment: Yes, misunderstood the question, have updated it for future reference i.e. if someone is facing same issue.